# Component not being unmounted

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to write a React mixin that creates a few keybindings to easily scroll list views, however, I have problems with removing the event listeners after the component has been removed from the DOM

Mixin:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    var requiredFunction = Object.getPrototypeOf(this).keyedList;
    if (!_.isFunction(requiredFunction)) {
      console.log('[KeyedListMixin] You must define the keyedList() function');
    }

    $(document).on('keydown', this.__handleKeyDown);
  },

  componentDidUnMount: function() {
    $(document).off('keydown', this.__handleKeyDown);
  },
```

render:

```
if (showNewCommentWindow) {
      centeredWindow   = (
        <FixedView>
          <div className='new-comment-window'>
            <NewResourceWindow
              listObjects       = {searchResults}
              onSearchItemClick = {this._handleSearchItemClick}
              handleOnChange    = {this._handleSearchChange}
              />
          </div>
        </FixedView>
      )
    }
return (
   ....
   {centeredWindow}
   ....
```

But once `showNewCommentWindow` is false, and as a result, the `FixedView` doesn't get rendered, the component don't unmount for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lifecycle method isn't called `componentDidUnMount`, it's called `componentWillUnmount`. Two important differences where the casing is `Unmount` and not `UnMount` and that it's `Will` and not `Did`. If it was called `componentDidUnmount` the component would have already been unmounted and the reference to the DOM node would have been released. So you clean up any DOM related things in `componentWillUnmount` just before the component is unmounted.